# Android: skip onCreate while going between activities

Tags: android

There are 2 activities. On first one I call an api to get some information in onCreate() method to show it on screen, and on second one I just show some faq. 
So, when I get back from my faq screen to main screen, onCreate is called again. Is it possible to skip it second time?

Comment: pls give some more information...for understand

Comment: Please share some code what you are trying. There may be way for skipping it second time, however one cannot tell how to do ti with this limited information

Answer (score 2):

You need to adapt your code to behave accordingly when the lifecycle callbacks happen.

Also, `onCreate()` will only get called if the Activity either was destroyed before, or it's created for the first time. Typically this will not happen when coming back to an `Activity` that has just left scope. (Check if you did set the developer option "Don't keep activities")

Answer (score 1):

Yes it is possible. Do the following steps

**Step 1:**

Call new Activity Intent without calling `finish();`

**Step 2:**

When you want to close `Activity B` just call `finish();`

And you need to understand the Activity Lifecycle which is help you to solve this.

Read the following:

> During normal app use, the foreground activity is sometimes obstructed
>   by other visual components that cause the activity to pause. For
>   example, when a semi-transparent activity opens (such as one in the
>   style of a dialog), the previous activity pauses. As long as the
>   activity is still partially visible but currently not the activity in
>   focus, it remains paused.

You can read developer site which gives more idea. http://developer.android.com/training/basics/activity-lifecycle/pausing.html also refer this http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html

Answer (score 0):

Are you calling finish () before starting new activity. If not then onCreate of activity A won't be called if you press back button. If yes then don't call  finish()

Answer (score 0):

System calls this callback so you don't have much control over it. What you need to do is not think about avoiding this callback but how to handle it properly. 
Please have a look at [`onSaveInstanceState`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html#onSaveInstanceState(android.os.Bundle)) and [`onRestoreInstanceState`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html#onRestoreInstanceState(android.os.Bundle))

Answer (score 0):

you must add the onResume() method.

if the activity is already created, the OnResume() method is called without recreating the activity

Please Check the lifecycle of the Activity here : [Activity](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html)

Answer (score -2):

Declare a static boolean in your class like

```
static boolean done
```

Then you write:

```
...
if(!done){
    ...your code
    done = true;
}
```

In you onCreate method. And that's it.

Comment: This is highly unnecessary since the framework provides ways to accomplish this goal easily.